# HC-SR04 Sensor using PIC24FJ256GA7 microcontroller

Tags: project, microcontroller, sensors, pic, mplab

I'm working on a project using the PIC24FJ256GA7 Curiosity board, and I must admit, MPLAB is still a bit new to me. So, I could really use some assistance!

Here's what I've got so far: I'm using the HC-SR04 sensor to detect human presence. When it senses someone within a specific range, I want to trigger an emergency LED and display a "Danger" message on Tera Term. Also, I'd like the same LED and message to activate when I press the Emergency Button. I was able to compile and program the code, but nothing seems to be happening. Could you kindly check my code and help me modify it? I'd also appreciate it if you could suggest any other code that might be useful for my project.

Here are the MCC settings and the code I've built:

MCC settings

HC-SR04 Sensor: Pin Configuration - 5V, GND, Trig (RB3 as GPIO Output), Echo (RB2 as GPIO Input), Peripheral - Timer

Emergency Button (RA11)

Emergency LED (RA8)

Tera Term (Driver Notification): UART1(Peripheral), Pins - RB7(U1Tx), RB8 (U1RX)

Code

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h" // Include the MCC configuration header

#include "mcc_generated_files/system.h" // Include the system header



#include <xc.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

#include <stdint.h>

#define FCY (4000000UL) 

#include <libpic30.h> // Include this for __delay_us and __delay_ms functions



// Configuration settings

#define TRIGGER_PIN LATBbits.LATB3

#define ECHO_PIN  PORTBbits.RB2

#define DANGER_DISTANCE_CM 30 // Adjust this value based on your requirement



// Function prototypes

void custom_delay_us(unsigned int us);

void custom_delay_ms(unsigned int ms);

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds);



// Function to perform some delay in microseconds

void custom_delay_us(unsigned int us) {

  while (us--) {

    __delay_us(1);

  }

}



// Function to perform some delay in milliseconds

void custom_delay_ms(unsigned int ms) {

  while (ms--) {

    __delay_ms(1);

  }

}



long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {

  return microseconds / 29 / 2;

}



// Handle the RA11 button press

void handleButtonPress() {

  LATAbits.LATA8 = 1; // Replace 'x' with the correct pin number for the LED

  printf("Danger\r\n");

  __delay_ms(500);

}





int main(void) {

  // Your peripherals are already configured through MCC.

  // You don't need to reconfigure them here.



  while (1) {

    long duration, cm;

    uint32_t startTime, endTime;



    TRIGGER_PIN = 0; // Set TRIGGER_PIN LOW

    custom_delay_us(2);

    TRIGGER_PIN = 1; // Set TRIGGER_PIN HIGH

    custom_delay_us(10);

    TRIGGER_PIN = 0; // Set TRIGGER_PIN LOW



    while (!ECHO_PIN); // Wait for ECHO_PIN to go HIGH

    startTime = TMR1; // Record the start time



    while (ECHO_PIN); // Wait for ECHO_PIN to go LOW

    endTime = TMR1; // Record the end time



    duration = endTime - startTime;

    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);



    if (cm <= DANGER_DISTANCE_CM) {

      // Turn on the Emergency LED to indicate danger

      LATAbits.LATA8 = 1;



      // Send "Danger" message to Tera Term via UART

      printf("Danger\r\n");



      // Add a delay to keep the LED on for a brief duration

      custom_delay_ms(500);

    } else {

      // Turn off the Emergency LED

      LATAbits.LATA8 = 0;

    }



    // Check if RA11 button is pressed

    if (PB1_GetValue() == 1) {

      handleButtonPress();

    }



    // Perform a delay of 100 milliseconds before taking the next measurement

    custom_delay_ms(100);

  }



  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where did you configure your ports and the other peripherals?